# RESTAngular: GET request - objects array

Tags: arrays, angularjs, playframework, request, restangular

I'm trying to make a simple get request for hours, but it just not working.
I have a service which responsible of the array , when I defined the array I call service that I built for the restAngular functions.

the first service:

```
app.factory('ServiceArray',function($filter,restAngularService){

        var Cards = restAngularService.getC();
        console.log(Cards);
return{
            getCards : function(){
                return Cards;
            }
}
//more code...

}
```

I get undefined from the console.log

the restAngular service :

```
 app.factory('restAngularService',function($filter,Restangular){
    var Accounts = Restangular.all('api');
    var baseAccounts = Accounts.one('get');
    return{
        getC : function(){
            var Cards = [];
            if(baseAccounts.get()){
                baseAccounts.getList().then(function(b) {
                    console.log(b.plain());
                    Cards = b.plain();
                    return Cards;

                });

            } else {
                return Cards = [{}];
            }
    }
}
```

from this console.log I get :

[Object, Object]

the controller code :

```
$scope.Cards = ServiceArray.getCards();
condole.log($scope.Cards);
```

I get undefined from the console.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to return a promise from your getC method like this:

```
app.factory('restAngularService',function($filter,Restangular, $q){
    var Accounts = Restangular.all('api');
    var baseAccounts = Accounts.one('get');

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    return{
        getC : function(){
            var Cards = [];
            if(baseAccounts.get()){
                baseAccounts.getList().then(function(b) {
                    console.log(b.plain()[0]);
                    Cards = b.plain()[0];
                    deferred.resolve(Cards);
                });
            } else {
                deferred.resolve([{}]);
            }

           return deferred.promise;
    }
}
```

And then you use this service in your controller like this:

```
var Cards;
restAngularService.getC().then(function(cards){
  Cards = cards;
  console.log(Cards);
});
```

***UPD*** since your method `baseAccounts.getList()` is asynchronous it returns promise. So you can't just call it synchronously. So you call it, and add a callback with `then`. And this callback will be executed when your promise is resolved (eg you get your JSON from the net)

Comment: I get: ReferenceError: deferred is not defined

Comment: provide dependency $q in parameter of your service. I think you missing it.

Comment: I did , it not recognize it

Comment: sorry, but it not suppose to be .plain()[0], that was my mistake, it suppose to get back an array

Comment: try to log $q.defer()

Comment: I fixed the problem with the $q , now its some thing else , please look at my question again I edited it

Comment: Code is looking like correct. again try to log ServiceArray.getCards()

Comment: when I do the same thing outside the service , in the controller its work

Comment: plz update restAngularService and use it directly in the controller, like i propose in the initial answer. if it works we'll proceed

Comment: or may be set up plunker so that i could fix it

Comment: it works like this, but I want it to work in the service, I don't get what is the difference

Comment: the difference is that restAngularService returns promise and your ServiceArray should do so to make it work

Comment: its not the problem, the var Crads in ServiceArray stays [] although it set the result from  restAngularService ...

Comment: even if I make only one service it still undefined

Comment: it is working, but still why my way wasn't ? i mean the way in the plunker :http://plnkr.co/edit/N5m9s8Nx7xEIf03OdNO0?p=catalogue